# Impedir que o R coloque as barras em ordem algabética no ggplot

Tags: classificação, ggplot2, gráfico

Pesquisei por uma resposta, mas acredito que por ser iniciante não encontrei uma solução que se adeque ao meu problema.
O ggplot coloca as barras e, consequentemente, a legenda pela ordem alfabética das categorias da variável "Score". Mas eu gostaria de manter a ordem original que é: Normal, Mild, Moderate, Severe e Extremely severe.

```
Fase <- c(rep(c("A"), 15), rep(c("T"), 15))
Outcome<- c(rep(c("Dep", "Axy", "Tes"), 2))
Score <- c(rep(c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Extremely severe"), 6))
Prev <- c(12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5, 12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5, 12, 23, 24, 41, 56, 6.0, 8.9, 54, 23, 24.5)
low = c(9, 17, 21, 38, 53, 2.7, 6, 50, 16, 20.7, 9, 19, 20, 39, 52, 3.5, 6.7, 48, 18, 22, 8.9, 15, 19.7, 38, 50, 4, 7, 52, 21, 21.9)
high = c(16, 25, 27, 45, 59, 7.8, 10, 59, 27, 27.3, 16, 27, 26, 43, 59, 9, 11, 58, 25, 29, 17, 25.5, 27, 44, 58, 8.5, 10.8, 57, 25.6, 26.7)
df <- data.frame(Fase = as.factor(Fase), Outcome = factor(Outcome), Score = as.factor(Score), Prev, low, high)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Outcome, y=Prev, fill=Score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = .8, color="black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= low, ymax= high), width = 0.3,
                position= position_dodge(width=.8)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .4, end = .9) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.6, size = 14, color = "red")) +
  ggtitle("") +
  facet_wrap(~Fase)
```

Vejam que a ordem da variável Outcome (Dep, Axy, Tes) também mudou, mas essa é menos importante.

Grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece pois qualquer fator no R por padrão é ordenado alfabeticamente, logo em sua criação ou posteriormente é necessário mudar isso. Usarei aqui uma solução com o pacote `forcats` que é especializado em fatores.

### Pacotes

```
library(dplyr)# Manipulação de dados
library(ggplot2)# Criação de gráficos
library(forcats)# Manipulação de fatores
```

### Apoio

```
#Vetores auxiliares com as ordens desejadas
ordem_score <- c("Normal", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Extremely severe")
ordem_outcome <- c("Dep", "Axy", "Tes")
```

### Gráfico

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    #Reordenação da variável escore segundo nosso vetor auxiliar
    Score = fct_relevel(Score,ordem_score),
    #Reordenação da variável outcome segundo nosso vetor auxiliar
    Outcome = fct_relevel(Outcome,ordem_outcome)
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Outcome, y=Prev, fill=Score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = .8, color="black") +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .4, end = .9) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.6, size = 14, color = "red")) +
  ggtitle("") +
  facet_wrap(~Fase)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Evite o uso de `attach`, trará muitos problemas e conflitos eventualmente

Comment: Muito obrigado, Vinícius Félix. Vou editar e adicionar as barras de erro que faltaram.

Comment: Por nada @Baptista . Peço só que aceite a resposta, pois isso facilita nas consultas!